# Apache file negotiation failed

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm having the following issue on a host using Apache 2.2.22 + PHP 5.4.0

I need to provide the file `/home/server1/htdocs/admin/contents.php` when a user makes the request: `http://server1/admin/contents`, but I obtain this message on the server error_log.

```
Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/server1/htdocs/admin/contents (None could be negotiated)
```

Notice that I have `mod_negotiation` enabled and MultiViews among the options for the related virtualhost:

```
<Directory "/home/server1/htdocs">
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I also use `mod_rewrite`, with the following `.htaccess` rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\./]*)$ index.php?t=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems very strange, but on the same box with PHP 5.3.6 it used to work correctly. I'm just trying an upgrade to PHP 5.4.0, but I cannot solve this negotiation issue. Any idea on why Apache cannot match `contents.php` when asking for `content` (which should be what mod_negotiation is supposed to do)?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that mod_negotiation behaves correctly with files with extension different than .php: so if I'd have a file named /admin/contents.txt, I can access it regulary with the browser with /admin/contents url. So the problem is only for php files. Any clue on what could make the negotiation fail?

Comment: How do you configure mod_negotiation? Are you using it?

Comment: Well I just include mod_negotiation in httpd.conf, then the MultiViews options in the VirtualHost should be enough to do what I'm looking for, as far as I know.. isn't it?

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem with `+MultiViews` enabled, and it dissapeared upon disabling it.

Comment: Adding Options -Multiviews at the top of .htaccess file worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, Apache 2.4.57, php7.4-fpm (not prefork module, but event module with php-fpm as fastcgi handler). The other option - namely, adding "AddType application/x-httpd-php php" in mods-enabled/mime.conf or /etc/mime.types did *not* work. See this for MultiViews: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-files-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found the solution. Very easy, indeed. I forgot to include the following:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

into apache mod_mime section into httpd.conf

I was misled by the fact that php scripts were correctly working; however the negotiation was failing because mod_negotiation only looks for "interesting" (and known) file types.

Comment: This! This right HERE!

Spent most of the night hunting down why I was getting the very unhelpful "Discovered File(s)/None Negotiated" error. Scripts had been working fine before, and I had a devil of a time tracking down the fact that the type wasn't being included in mod_mime on the distribution I was testing on. I owe you a beer sir.

Comment: I'll gladly accept your beer when I'll come to US :)

Comment: this works perfectly!! @lorenzo.marcon thanks for the question and answer!

Comment: This must have changed at some point. I'm feeling pretty confident I didn't need to add this earlier for php MultiViews to work.

Comment: Thanks a metric ton! I was banging my head against the wall, wondering why my mod rewrite from search/?$ to search.php wasn't working. Seems the negoitiation module has precedence over the rewrite module which is generally good to know.

Comment: Thanks I struggle for 2 hours, I would never have found !

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem after updating from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy.  The `mods-enabled/mime.conf` includes the known file types from the system:

```
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
```

The problem was that the `/etc/mime.types` file was replaced by the update and in the replaced file, the PHP part was commented out. When searching for it, I found:

```
#application/x-httpd-php                        phtml pht php
#application/x-httpd-php-source                 phps
#application/x-httpd-php3                       php3
#application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed          php3p
#application/x-httpd-php4                       php4
#application/x-httpd-php5                       php5
```

I had to remove the `#` from each line containing php-relevant stuff, then save and restart the Apache web server. That solved the problem without modifying the `mime.conf` file.

Comment: This saved me after 4hs of unending debugging against a ghost.

Comment: Be aware that doing this might make `libapache-mod-php5` execute files with `.php` in the name (like `filename.php.jpeg`) which was the original rationale for commenting them out.  See https://bugs.debian.org/589384

Comment: @Kevinoid This is a very big security issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of mapping `.php` to a media type (which can have security implications, as described in [Debian Bug 589384](https://bugs.debian.org/589384) which disabled them), you can configure [`MultiviewsMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch) to match files without a type for `.php`, as suggested in [Mark Amery's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24598848):

```
<Files "*.php">
    MultiviewsMatch Any
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy. The mods-enabled/mime.conf includes the known file types from the system:

```
 TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
```

The problem was that the /etc/mime.types file was replaced by the update and in the replaced file, the PHP part was commented out. When searching for it, I found:

```
#application/x-httpd-php                        phtml pht php
#application/x-httpd-php-source                 phps
#application/x-httpd-php3                       php3
#application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed          php3p
#application/x-httpd-php4                       php4
#application/x-httpd-php5                       php5
```

I had to remove the `#` from each line containing php-relevant stuff, then save and restart the Apache web server. That solved the problem without modifying the mime.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Xammp with virtual hosts, the error with mod_rewrite was remove in httpd-vhosts.conf at <Directory "YourPath">

Instead

> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

Put

> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

Source: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Apache/1422809-solucionado-Negotiation-discovered-files-matching-request.html

Greetings.